# Could not find method getAccessibilityNodeProvider

Tags: android, warnings, logcat, numberpicker

I am using the number selector simonvt library (https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker).

I added the library successfully and the application runs normally, but the LogCat is showing these warnings:

```
Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.getAccessibilityNodeProvider, referenced from method net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker.getAccessibilityNodeProvider
```

The complete log:

```
10-08 18:13:36.152: I/dalvikvm(489): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.getAccessibilityNodeProvider, referenced from method net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker.getAccessibilityNodeProvider
10-08 18:13:36.152: W/dalvikvm(489): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5439: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.getAccessibilityNodeProvider ()Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeProvider;
10-08 18:13:36.162: D/dalvikvm(489): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0004
10-08 18:13:36.172: W/dalvikvm(489): Unable to resolve superclass of Lnet/simonvt/numberpicker/NumberPicker$AccessibilityNodeProviderImpl; (701)
10-08 18:13:36.182: W/dalvikvm(489): Link of class 'Lnet/simonvt/numberpicker/NumberPicker$AccessibilityNodeProviderImpl;' failed
10-08 18:13:36.192: W/dalvikvm(489): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeProvider;)
10-08 18:13:36.192: D/dalvikvm(489): VFY: dead code 0x0007-0007 in Lnet/simonvt/numberpicker/NumberPicker;.getAccessibilityNodeProvider ()Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeProvider;
10-08 18:13:36.212: I/dalvikvm(489): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent, referenced from method net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent
10-08 18:13:36.212: W/dalvikvm(489): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5449: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent;)V
10-08 18:13:36.232: D/dalvikvm(489): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
10-08 18:13:36.232: D/dalvikvm(489): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0026 in Lnet/simonvt/numberpicker/NumberPicker;.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent;)V
```

The sample project shows these warnings too!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What device are you running this on? The method [`android.widget.LinearLayout.getAccessibilityNodeProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getAccessibilityNodeProvider%28%29) was added in API level 16 (Jelly Bean 4.1) according to the docs. So it won't work on Ice Cream Sandwich or lower devices. Try the simulator to see if that works.